# LINQ to SQL running direct SQL for a scalar value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am trying to execute the following raw SQL as LINQ has no proper support for `DateDiff`:

```
var str = @"SELECT ISNULL(AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, AddedDate, PresentDate)), 0)
              AS Days
                FROM DummyTable";
```

Using LINQ to SQL, I'm trying to get the output of the above statement using:

```
var numberOfDays = Math.Round(db.ExecuteQuery<double>(str).FirstOrDefault());
```

This give me the error: `Specified cast is not valid.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

Looks like the cast was indeed wrong... Changed the line to:

```
var numberOfDays = db.ExecuteQuery<int>(str).FirstOrDefault();
```

And all is well!

Comment: Accept other user's answers, not yourself.

Comment: @AgentFire: If you take the time to notice post times, you would see that I figured it before the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code must change to:

```
var numberOfDays = db.ExecuteQuery<int>(str).FirstOrDefault());
```

You think why? I tell you:

Return type of DateDiff in int.So Return Type of AVG will be int. So Return Type of IsNULL will be int too.

References :
[DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
[AVG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)

IsNull always try to convert the type of second expression to first expression.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF()` returns an `int`. When passed a collection of integers, the `AVG()` function returns an integer as well. Try this code instead:

```
    var numberOfDays = db.ExecuteQuery<int>(str).FirstOrDefault();
```